# Laravel Nova - Problems with distinct()

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am using Laravel Nova to generate metrics, in this case specifically a trend. Here is my code:

```
$builder = order::query()->select('cook_id')->distinct();
return $this->countByDays($request, $builder)->showLatestValue();
```

However this is returning 6 - but it should be 4.

Yes there are 6 rows, but four of them have the same 'cook_id' and thus the distinct call should be eliminating 2 of those.

To reiterate, this is in Laravel Nova's "trend" metric.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old post, but for anyone having the same problem, you can use a raw expression to allow for the distinct query.

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
{

    return $this->aggregate($request,
        order::class,
        self::BY_DAYS,
        'count',
        DB::raw('distinct cook_id'),
    );
}
```

By using DB::raw, nova will accept the column as is and not attempt to wrap it.

Comment: is there any way we completely overwrite and show result based on custom query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use groupBy

```
$builder = order::distinct()->select('cook_id')->groupBy('cook_id')->get();
```

also in `database.php` set mysql strict to `false`

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'strict' => false
]
```

Comment: Thanks, may I ask why I should set mySql to false? What does this do?

Comment: Thanks again, I have now tried your solution and it produces the same results that I have been seeing with every other variation of the query. It is counting 2 rows with the same cook ID as 2, and not 1.

Comment: You can read about strict mode here https://mattstauffer.com/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2/

Comment: Also try with distinct('cook_id') and groupBy('cook_id')

Comment: Nope - I appreciate your help here but it seems like this "trends" mfunction just completely ignores distinct. It's maddening. I've written the query every which way imaginable.... and there are lots of ways to write it. None work.